# Getting all data from one table, while another table is empty and where clause is also applied

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Two Tables: Employees and Salaries

I am getting all records from Employees even if salaries table is empty by using left Join, But when i used **where** on salaries table, it doesn't get me all employees.

How can i get all employees records???????

```
SELECT `s`.`basic_salary`,`e`.`name` 
FROM (`employees` as e) 
LEFT JOIN `salaries` as s ON `s`.`employee_id`=`e`.`employee_id` 
WHERE `s`.`session_id` = '19' AND `s`.`month_id` = '7' 
GROUP BY `e`.`employee_id`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition on the second table needs to go into the `on` clause:

```
SELECT s.`basic_salary`, e.`name` 
FROM `employees` e LEFT JOIN
     `salaries` s
     ON `s`.`employee_id`=`e`.`employee_id` AND
        `s`.`session_id` = '19' AND `s`.`month_id` = '7' 
GROUP BY e.`employee_id`
```

Otherwise you turn the outer join into an inner join.

Comment: @GhufranJaved . . . Did you find that this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` in your query is cancelling the effect of `LEFT JOIN` as you're expecting `s.session_id` and `s.month_id` to have value. If what you want is to filter the employees whose salary is null or matches a certain condition you could try:

```
SELECT `s`.`basic_salary`,`e`.`name` 
FROM (`employees` as e) 
LEFT JOIN `salaries` as s ON `s`.`employee_id`=`e`.`employee_id` 
WHERE (`s`.`session_id` = '19' AND `s`.`month_id` = '7' OR `s`.`employee_id` IS NULL) 
GROUP BY `e`.`employee_id`
```

Comment: Please, close the question selecting an answer as correct then